# Need to get country, state , city and area on entering pincode value in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation, ip, npm

I am developing a web application using nodeJs and ejs. I need to update country, state , city and area automatically depending on the pin-code(zip-code) entered. Is there any package available in node js or any other method available to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cities](https://github.com/sjlu/cities) to lookup cities based on zipcodes or GPS coordinates. It will return you json as below.

```
{
  zipcode: "07946",
  state_abbr: "NJ",
  latitude: "40.672823",
  longitude: "-74.52011",
  city: "Millington",
  state: "New Jersey"
}
```

This package will be only searchable for US. For all countries, you can import data from [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) using [this package](https://github.com/mattes/geonames-postal-codes-import-nodejs) to database. *(Only MySQL supported for now)*

That package also won't have updated data, but so far, that's the best I've seen before.

Comment: I need to get country also.

Comment: @Khay - As you mention the cities package (https://github.com/sjlu/cities) only support for US only.

Comment: I tried the updated answer. But my db is PostgreSQL. I have made few changes in the index.js file. But still I was stuck in the insert method function dbInsert(values, successCallback). I am getting error: syntax error at or near ","

Comment: Finally I used mysql and imported from mysql to postgress using kettle.

Answer (score 3):

I found this package useful & for some reason felt this is easy to use :

[zipcodes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zipcodes)

Had a simple get API with a path param & response looks like this :

[image]